# C : printf function not printing when I input element of an array

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to print an element of the `cube_pattern` string, but when I execute my code nothing is printed to the console and my code freezes for a few seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SOLVED_CUBE "UUUUUUUUURRRRRRRRRFFFFFFFFFDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLBBBBBBBBB"

char cube_pattern[54] = SOLVED_CUBE

void print_pattern() {
    printf("%s", cube_state[0]);
}

void main() {
    print_pattern();
}
```

I tried calling `fflush(stdout)` but it still doesn't work:

```
void print_pattern() {
    printf("%s", cube_state[0]);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: `cube_state[0]` is a `char`, `%s` expects a `char*` to a null-terminated byte string. 2 very different things

Comment: There are SO many things wrong with your code snippet.. a) "cube_pattern[]" <> "cube_state[]", b) [54] should probably be "[]" (and might leave off the null byte - I didn't count, c) the line needs ";" (did the code even compile)? and d) printf("s%") requires a CHARACTER ARRAY (not a single character!).  ALSO: "it still doesn't work" is HOPELESSLY VAGUE!  What exactly is your question?  What did you expect, and what happened instead?

Answer (score 1):

`"UUUUUUUUURRRRRRRRRFFFFFFFFFDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLBBBBBBBBB"` contains 54 characters. Your char array only can store 54 characters. This does not leave space for a null terminator. Thus when you try to print using the `%s` specifier, you invoke undefined behavior. Maybe when it looks for the 55th character, it finds `0`, but maybe not.

I don't see that using `#define` gains you anything. I would simply:

```
char cube_pattern[] = "UUUUUUUUURRRRRRRRRFFFFFFFFFDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLBBBBBBBBB";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple errors. First, you have multiple typos. For example, `cube_state` should be `cube_pattern`. Second, you are using the `printf()` formatter `%s`, but only passing it one character (`cube_pattern[0]`). Lastly, your array is only 54 bytes long, but your string needs 55 bytes (54 characters + one NULL character).

This code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char cube_pattern[55] = "UUUUUUUUURRRRRRRRRFFFFFFFFFDDDDDDDDDLLLLLLLLLBBBBBBBBB";

void print_pattern() {
    printf("%s\n", cube_pattern);
}

int main() {
    print_pattern();
}
```

I have also changed `printf("%s", cube_pattern);` to `printf("%s\n", cube_pattern);`. Adding a new line will flush the buffer if your output is line-buffered, which is generally what you want. Alternatively, you could also use `fflush(stdout)`.